# Python mean, median, var, and std function

Tags: python

How do I do this so it will run
Replace (??MEAN_FUNCTION??) with the name of Python function that calculates the mean.

Replace ??MEDIAN_FUNCTION?? with the name of Python function that calculates the median.

Replace ??VAR_FUNCTION?? with the name of Python function that calculates the variance.

Replace ??STD_FUNCTION?? with the name of Python function that calculates the standard deviation.

```
   mean = your_team_df['elo_n']??MEAN_FUNCTION??()
    median = your_team_df['elo_n']??MEDIAN_FUNCTION??()
    variance = your_team_df['elo_n']??VAR_FUNCTION??()
    stdeviation = your_team_df['elo_n'].??STD_FUNCTION??()

    print('Mean =', round(mean,2))
    print('Median =', round(median,2))
    print('Variance =', round(variance,2))
    print('Standard Deviation =', round(stdeviation,2))
```

Comment: Assuming you are using a pandas DataFrame, try looking for a proper method in: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html#computations-descriptive-stats

Comment: The [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) module might come in handy here.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: A few things, I have to write a report on this but first I have to find out how to do the mean function, median function, var function, and std function to make it calculate the data

Comment: please help me and post the code

Comment: I will upvote the correct answer

Comment: mean = your_team_df['elo_n'].mean()
median = your_team_df['elo_n'].median()
variance = your_team_df['elo_n'].var()
stdeviation = your_team_df['elo_n'].std()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? I am unsure of it.

Code:

```
mean = your_team_df['elo_n'].mean()
median = your_team_df['elo_n'].median()
variance = your_team_df['elo_n'].var()
stdeviation = your_team_df['elo_n'].std()

print(f"Mean = {mean:.2f}")
print(f"Median = {median:.2f}")
print(f"Variance = {variance:.2f}")
print(f"Standard Deviation = {stdeviation:.2f}")
```

Comment: yes but i figured it out right before you posted it

Comment: why does no one want to help people out on here?

Comment: @heyhey Well, I think that some words in your question was a little bit difficult to understand. Anyway, happy to help you out.